# Want to run MAgento 2.0 only in Thai language

Tags: magento2, multistore, language

I want to run a magento site only in the Thai language and not in english for SEO optimization. Is that possible for do i have run it in English also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento2 Thai language package. Just install it most of the words will be translated.

https://github.com/jucksearm/magento2-language-th-th